# socket threading.Thread args takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, multithreading, args

```
import threading
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9999))
sock.listen(5)

def handle_client(sock_client):
        data = sock_client.recv(4096)
        while data:
                sock_client.send("this is server: " + data)
                data = sock_client.recv(4096)
        sock_client.close()

while True:
        client = sock.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=client)
        t.start()
```

TypeError: handle_client() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

this Why, my thread args only give a parameter, why tell me to give two parameters.

how to understand this?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling threading function in the wrong way. Currently, You use this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=client)
```

However, You should use this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, ))
```

If You read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), You'll see that `args` parameter should be a tuple, and not a single variable.

**Update:**

Just tested my code, it works fine. Yes, program will still raise an error (`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recv'`), but this is because You should use `sock_client[0]` to receive data (`sock_client` itself is a tuple consisting of connection object and address).

So, proper code is here:

```
import threading
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9999))
sock.listen(5)

def handle_client(sock_client):
        conn = sock_client[0]
        address = sock_client[1]
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        while data:
                conn.send("this is server: " + data)
                data = conn.recv(4096)
        conn.close()

while True:
        client = sock.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, ))
        t.start()
```

Comment: But the final results are the same, when only one parameter, not a tuple , it will be converted into a tuple.
-> /root/s.py(10)handle_client()
-> sock_client = args[0]
(Pdb) p args
((<socket._socketobject object at 0x7f0bb2ddde50>, ('172.16.0.48', 49524)),)

Comment: What do You mean by "the effect is same"? Do You receive same error again?

Comment: Is not the case, the original is client = sock.accpet () returns a tuple, it should be client, addr = sock.accept(),  so there is no problem, the main problem is the accept() return the value that I am not clear.

Comment: It should be? I don't see that part in your code. Did You even tried to debug the code?

Comment: And what is the EXACT issue You have?

Comment: yes, i think. if handle_client handle tuple is complex.